# Ir adicionando valores do for no array

Tags: javascript, jquery, loop, for

Criei um array:

```
var tagListArray = [];

 for(i = 0; i<resultados.item(i); i++){
    tagListArray = ["valor1", "valor2"];
 }

console.log(tagListArray);
```

Esse `resultados.item(i)` me retorna x valores, como faço para ir adicionando no array?

Fiz assim para testar:

```
var tagListArray = ["Maçã", "Banana"];
                                var data = new Object({data:[]});
                                var index;  

                                for(index = 0; index < results.rows.length; index++) {
                                    alert(results.rows.item(index).descricao);
                                    data.data.push({
                                        tag: tagListArray[index]
                                    });
                                };
```

Mas, no tagListArray quero que os valores sejam preenchidos com o que o laço de repetição retorna.

Comment: `resultados.item(i)` é uma array? Qual a estrutura?

Comment: @Sam não é um array.

Comment: Tem que ver como é retornado para saber como fazer o loop.

Comment: resultados.item(i) tem os valores a e b.

se dou console.log quando termina o for ele me retorna ab.

Comment: Tem que informar como é esse retorno, se é uma string, um objeto... array vc já disse que não é.

Comment: É uma string...

Comment: Realmente não consegui entender o que deseja. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Use o comando `push()` para adicionar um novo item no `array`:

```js
tagListArray.push("String");
```

Se for uma lista de objeto pode usar ele do mesmo jeito:

```js
tagListArray.push({
  ID: 1,
  Nome: "Valor 1"
});
```